# I don't understand how to catch an error

Tags: r

II don't understand how to catch an error.

For example i wrote a script:

```
morph_input = tryCatch(prepareMorphObjectFromFiles(InputConfig,InputGOI),
              error=stop("Please Start Over,your Data Sets or uploaded GOI are not suitable."))
```

I want that if the function `prepareMorphObjectFromFiles(InputConfig,InputGOI)` will break, just then the error will pop out. but it always pop out even if the function didn't break.

Comment: The argument to error should be a function, not a function call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass an error handling **function** as the `error` argument in `tryCatch()`. Otherwise it indeed will always be evaluated. An example:

```
tryCatch({
   if (runif(1) > 0.8) stop("catch me if you can!")
   else "OK"
},
error=function(err) {
   # an error handler
   cat("An error occured.\n")
})
```

Comment: i wrote this:`morph_input = tryCatch(prepareMorphObjectFromFiles(InputConfig,InputGOI),     error =function(err){stop("Please Start Over,your Data Sets or uploaded GOI are not suitable.")
                         })`and still it doesn't work

Comment: @dmitriy So you catch the error... only to throw another error.  Do you see the problem?

Comment: @dmitriy Although you still should only get an error if there was an error in the input expression.  We don't know if there was so can't say much more.

Answer (score 2):

@gagolews gives what most would prefer.  I like using just `try` and it helps me to think more linear about my code (i.e. in steps).

```
out <- try({
   if (runif(1) > .7) stop("catch me if you can!")
   else "OK"
}, silent = TRUE)

if(inherits(out, "try-error")) message("went bad")
```