# apply function stops running when there is an error for one row of the data

Tags: r, apply

I am using apply function to execute a function for each row of my data. I found if one row of the data triggers  an error, I will not get result back. I wonder if there is a way to let the apply function give an error or NA for that problematic row but still run for the other rows.

Comment: For error handling, try using e.g. `tryCatch`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021775/i-dont-understand-how-to-catch-an-error/22021936#22021936) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your applied function in a `tryCatch` that will return NA if it fails.

Stop if x less than zero:

```
> foo = function(x){if(x<0)stop("Zerrored");sqrt(x)}
```

Try it

```
> apply(matrix(0:5),1,foo)
[1] 0.000000 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068

> apply(matrix(-2:5),1,foo)
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : Zerrored
```

Darn. Wrap in a `tryCatch`:

```
> tryfoo=function(x){tryCatch(foo(x),error=function(e){NA})}
> apply(matrix(-2:5),1,tryfoo)
[1]       NA       NA 0.000000 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068
```

Works!

You might want to raise a warning if the function errors:

```
> tryfoo=function(x){tryCatch(foo(x),error=function(e){warning("Zerrored");NA})}
> apply(matrix(-2:5),1,tryfoo)
[1]       NA       NA 0.000000 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068
Warning messages:
1: In value[[3L]](cond) : Zerrored
2: In value[[3L]](cond) : Zerrored
```

Again it doesn't stop the apply.

Comment: I have more than one arguments to be passed to the function. Would you please tell me how to pass multiple arguments in the tryCatch function. Thank you!

Comment: If your function is `foo(a,b,c)` then `tryfoo` is a `function(a,b,c)` and you pass those through to your `foo` function inside.